# URLSession trowing an NSURLSession exception

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta3

Swift 3 on Xcode 8β3.

Any ideas why the code below is throwing the error (further) below, particularly given that I am using *URLSession* not *NSURLSession*?

**CODE**

```
public func updateCurrentConditions() {

    let session = URLSession()
    let url     = URL(string: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/\(key)/conditions/51.32,-1.0.json")!
    let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: self.dataHandler) 
    loadDataTask.resume()
}

private func dataHandler(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void {
    print("dataHandler executed.")
}
```

**ERROR**

failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[NSURLSession dataTaskForRequest:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac89569f00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `shared` `URLSession`?

```
let session = URLSession.shared
```

The default initializer of `URLSession` is undefined, so it may be creating something weird...

Comment: Ah, I had tried a couple of similar variants but as instance rather than static functions.  That works.  Well, it compiles and runs anyway.  Still  not calling the completion handle though.  :(

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan, I believe your code (with `shared` fixed) should work. (Tested in a sample project with using another URL.) Check your URL, key, ATS settings... Hope you can solve those issues soon.

Comment: Interesting.  Works fine when embedded in a (single view) application but appears not to call the completion handler when embedded in a Cocoa Touch framework.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan, really interesting. If you can create a simplified example which can reproduce your issue, many readers would take their time to solve the issue. Simplifying would also help you solve your issue yourself.

Comment: it doesn't answer the question - `URLSession` has initializers and they should work but it seems you need to customize additionally some params which are obligatory but apple doesn't mention it